# BLE Advertisement Scanning scans very few advertisements very slowly on one Andriod device compared to another - Android V9 versus Androoid V7

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two devices running a simple BLE scanner, exact same code. Device A, Mecer M86Q9 tablet running android 7 scans about 80 adverts in 5 seconds while device B, Webfleet PRO8475 running androoid 9 only scans about 6 adverts in 5 seconds. Any suggestions on why the second device scans so few adverts and ways to fix this. I have attaced the logs from each device and my code for reference. Any help would this would be really appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
    public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
    public static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 3;

    //Setup Bluetooth Adapters
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView infoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewInfo);
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopScan);
        //Setup the BLE Scanner
        this.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        checkBtPermissions();
        enableBt();
        Log.i("Deploy Version","3");

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkPermission(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION
                );

                checkPermission(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION
                );
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
                } else {

                    infoText.setText("Scan Started");
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            scanLeDevice(false);
                        }
                    }.start();

                }
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                infoText.setText("Scan Stopped");
                scanLeDevice(false);
            }
        });

    }

    private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        String mAddress[] = {};


        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("BLE Advert", String.valueOf(result.getDevice().getAddress()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.i("locCheck", "inn errorstate");
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Log.i("BLE", "error");
        }
    };

    //Check Permissions
    public void checkPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            // Requesting the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{permission},
                    requestCode);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Permission already granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    //Check BT Perrmissions
    public void checkBtPermissions() {
        this.requestPermissions(
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
                },
                REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    //Enable Bluetooth
    public void enableBt() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_BT_ENABLE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        Log.i("locCheck", "in Le scan");

        if (enable) {

            ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                    .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
                    .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
                    .setReportDelay(0L)
                    .build();
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, mLeScanCallback);


        } else {
            Log.i("Scanning", "stop");
            //  mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

}
```

**Logs from Device A**

```
2021-06-10 16:39:51.156 1183-1183/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-10 16:39:51.193 1183-1183/? D/Zygote: runOnce: Connection end
2021-06-10 16:39:51.344 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons-2/lib/arm
2021-06-10 16:39:52.071 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2021-06-10 16:39:52.409 1183-1198/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/art: Enter while loop.
2021-06-10 16:39:52.813 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-06-10 16:39:52.976 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
2021-06-10 16:39:52.977 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Deploy Version: 3
2021-06-10 16:39:52.997 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@b134718[]
2021-06-10 16:39:53.117 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@b134718[MainActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@a3007dd
2021-06-10 16:39:53.157 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 2 threads <0xa127b140>
2021-06-10 16:39:53.158 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: <za.co.smartee.scanbeacons> is running.
2021-06-10 16:39:53.162 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa5a65000
2021-06-10 16:39:53.218 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa30d9930) (w:576 h:576 s:576 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
2021-06-10 16:39:53.284 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{ac6df52 za.co.smartee.scanbeacons/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity,ident = 0}
2021-06-10 16:39:53.289 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{ac6df52 za.co.smartee.scanbeacons/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@b134718[MainActivity]
2021-06-10 16:39:53.919 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x950a6700)
2021-06-10 16:39:53.919 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa5a65000 initialize window=0x950a6700, title=za.co.smartee.scanbeacons/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity
2021-06-10 16:39:53.926 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-10 16:39:53.926 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-06-10 16:39:53.927 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0xac03db40)
2021-06-10 16:39:53.931 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.init: enable enhancement 1
2021-06-10 16:39:53.931 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Get disable program binary service property (0)
2021-06-10 16:39:53.931 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
2021-06-10 16:39:53.934 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable debugging.
2021-06-10 16:39:53.934 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable binary content debugging.
2021-06-10 16:39:53.934 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getReady
2021-06-10 16:39:53.937 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryData
2021-06-10 16:39:53.938 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 91876, program map length is 124.
2021-06-10 16:39:53.938 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 52, and path is /dev/ashmem.
2021-06-10 16:39:53.938 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(52).
2021-06-10 16:39:53.939 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0x0, size = -1
2021-06-10 16:39:53.944 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/[MALI][Gralloc]: dlopen libsec_mem.so fail
2021-06-10 16:39:53.945 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x950a6700,api=1)
2021-06-10 16:39:53.946 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
2021-06-10 16:39:53.948 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x950a6700,bufferCount=4)
2021-06-10 16:39:54.148 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-10 16:39:54.274 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa5a06730) (w:800 h:1280 s:800 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
2021-06-10 16:39:54.280 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 1024, 169
2021-06-10 16:39:54.280 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 0
2021-06-10 16:39:54.289 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738371
2021-06-10 16:39:54.290 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 240518168576
2021-06-10 16:39:54.291 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 68724719680
2021-06-10 16:39:54.330 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa5a06880) (w:800 h:1280 s:800 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
2021-06-10 16:39:54.646 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
2021-06-10 16:39:54.672 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa5a06810) (w:800 h:1280 s:800 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
2021-06-10 16:39:54.731 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{ac6df52 za.co.smartee.scanbeacons/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@b134718[MainActivity]
2021-06-10 16:40:25.785 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103084458052
2021-06-10 16:40:26.099 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/locCheck: in Le scan
2021-06-10 16:40:26.105 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothLeScanner: startScan
2021-06-10 16:40:26.107 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-06-10 16:40:26.107 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
2021-06-10 16:40:26.123 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-06-10 16:40:26.196 1183-1200/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
2021-06-10 16:40:26.196 1183-1200/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothLeScanner: mClientIf=0
2021-06-10 16:40:26.215 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity$3@fb2b8bd=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@2906eb2}
2021-06-10 16:40:26.279 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 12, 1024, 147
2021-06-10 16:40:26.282 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{b484581 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@a3007dd
2021-06-10 16:40:26.291 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa5a68800
2021-06-10 16:40:26.293 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{8e58e03 Toast,ident = 1}
2021-06-10 16:40:26.370 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x950a6000)
2021-06-10 16:40:26.370 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa5a68800 initialize window=0x950a6000, title=Toast
2021-06-10 16:40:26.370 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x950a6000,api=1)
2021-06-10 16:40:26.372 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
2021-06-10 16:40:26.375 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x950a6000,bufferCount=4)
2021-06-10 16:40:26.390 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa5a068f0) (w:294 h:59 s:304 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
2021-06-10 16:40:26.393 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 27, 1024, 271
2021-06-10 16:40:26.393 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 1
2021-06-10 16:40:26.457 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:26.459 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:26.460 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:26.460 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D

2021-06-10 16:40:28.580 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:28.612 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E4:80:C2:22:67:AF
2021-06-10 16:40:28.680 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:28.701 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:28.771 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:28.777 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:28.858 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 42:EC:62:50:DD:3D
2021-06-10 16:40:28.883 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:28.900 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:29.046 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:29.048 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:29.069 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:29.111 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:29.317 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:29.321 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:29.325 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:29.535 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:29.544 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: F2:1D:AF:FB:6D:76
2021-06-10 16:40:29.566 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E7:10:65:87:1D:03
2021-06-10 16:40:29.736 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:29.765 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: F9:49:AD:84:42:45
2021-06-10 16:40:29.799 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:29.857 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:29.862 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:29.983 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:30.046 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.084 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x950a6000,api=1)
2021-06-10 16:40:30.085 1183-1262/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xa5a068f0) (w:294 h:59 s:304 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
2021-06-10 16:40:30.097 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{bf23267 V.E...... ........ 0,0-294,59}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@a3007dd
2021-06-10 16:40:30.127 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:30.133 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:30.256 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.347 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:30.360 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.406 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:30.415 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:30.467 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.530 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:30.544 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: F2:1D:AF:FB:6D:76
2021-06-10 16:40:30.559 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E7:10:65:87:1D:03
2021-06-10 16:40:30.570 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.612 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E4:80:C2:22:67:AF
2021-06-10 16:40:30.674 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:30.679 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:40:30.709 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:30.781 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.887 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:30.895 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:40:30.992 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:31.197 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:40:31.217 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:40:31.221 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/locCheck: in Le scan
2021-06-10 16:40:31.221 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Scanning: stop
2021-06-10 16:40:31.221 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothLeScanner: stopScan
2021-06-10 16:40:31.224 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-06-10 16:40:31.224 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
2021-06-10 16:40:31.224 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity$3@fb2b8bd=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@2906eb2} ,callback=za.co.smartee.scanbeacons.MainActivity$3@fb2b8bd
2021-06-10 16:40:31.229 1183-1183/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
```

**Logs From Device B**

```
2021-06-10 16:45:06.503 15838-15838/? I/tee.scanbeacon: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-10 16:45:06.960 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2021-06-10 16:45:07.120 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.120 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.120 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.120 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.120 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.191 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.210 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.279 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.281 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.513 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Deploy Version: 3
2021-06-10 16:45:07.541 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2021-06-10 16:45:07.618 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons W/tee.scanbeacon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-06-10 16:45:07.648 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 94a5458, I21281c58c8
    Build Date                       : 12/18/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.6.2.R1.09.00.00.463.046
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-06-10 16:45:07.649 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2021-06-10 16:45:07.654 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2021-06-10 16:45:07.660 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-06-10 16:45:07.661 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-06-10 16:45:07.661 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-10 16:45:07.661 15838-15866/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2021-06-10 16:45:22.103 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/locCheck: in Le scan
2021-06-10 16:45:22.105 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2021-06-10 16:45:22.111 15838-15851/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=8 mScannerId=0
2021-06-10 16:45:23.561 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:45:23.589 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 3B:0B:AC:C4:96:94
2021-06-10 16:45:23.600 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: DC:A9:04:7F:E0:95
2021-06-10 16:45:23.610 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 76:D6:06:1C:B7:3A
2021-06-10 16:45:23.614 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: 4E:25:9A:48:0F:83
2021-06-10 16:45:25.655 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/BLE Advert: E0:F1:AC:0B:64:9D
2021-06-10 16:45:27.117 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/locCheck: in Le scan
2021-06-10 16:45:27.117 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons I/Scanning: stop
2021-06-10 16:45:27.119 15838-15838/za.co.smartee.scanbeacons D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
```